# Can't import functions between scripts when using VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm workig in VS code and have cloned an internal repository.This repository comes with some default scripts. I can start a container and open up jupyter notebook from this. If I do that I can easily use functions across the different scripts like if want to get function Z  `from sql.sql_import import Z`. But if I try to do exaclty the same thing but in VS code, it keeps saying **"No module named sql.sql_import"** and **"sql is not a package"**.
Do you guys know what can be done to solve this?
I'm pretty new to this, but I hope it makes sense.

The code I use in the script where I want to import the function:

```
from sql.sql_import import Z
```

A section of the project structure:

```
AnonymizedEmbeddings
├─ Makefile
├─ README.md
├─ src
│  ├─ main
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ import_data.py
│  └─ sql
│     ├─ __init__.py  
│     └─ sql_import.py
```

I have tried moving around the scripts so they are in the same folder

Comment: Do you have a \_\_init\_\_.py file in your folder ?

Comment: @rochard4u Yes I have tried adding "__init__.py" in all the folders I have

Comment: check the folder in which your workspace is. example, when you open terminal, the last word on the terminal line is your current working directory. paths should be from here

Comment: @manjy In the terminal it looks like this: xxx@xxx:~/AnonymizedEmbeddings/src/main when I try to run the import_data.py (see edit in post, I have linked picture of structure)

Comment: @Mads-EmilHvidRasmussen I dont see src in the picture you have uploaded. also from which file are you trying to import, and what are you trying to import

Comment: @manjy My bad I have updated the picture. Im trying to import a function from sql_import.py into the script import_data.py

Comment: Please replace the image with a text in the question! [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)! Better format the question: `from X.Y import Z` not "from X.Y import Z"!

Comment: Try `from src.main.import_data import Z`! You need the relative path to the root directory of the project.

Comment: @MohammedSamir By doing that I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: You don’t have `__init__.py` in your `src` directory, so it’s not recognized as a module/package. Try adding an empty `__init__.py` there and use `from src.main.import_data import Z`.

Comment: @Ash I have now tried adding a ```__init__.py``` file to the src directory, but ```from src.main.import_data import Z``` results in this: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'```. The ```sql_import.py``` is located in the sql folder, so shouldn't it be ```from src.sql.sql_import import Z``` as is want to get a function from ```sql_import.py``` to ```import_data.py```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712742/8464994
currently you are in main directory, you need to import modules from parent directory, i.e. source, so try this solution about importing modules from parent directory

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code at the top of the `import_data.py` code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./src")
```

[image]

*If you are willing to move the script to the same folder, you can import directly without the above method.*

Answer (score 0):

Add following line on top of your code :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
```

Check the following source out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712742/8464994